# find all words in a certain alphabet with multi character letters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to find out what words can be formed using the names of musical notes.

This question is very similar: [Python code that will find words made out of specific letters. Any subset of the letters could be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661032/python-code-that-will-find-words-made-out-of-specific-letters-any-subset-of-the)
But my alphabet also contains "fis","cis" and so on.

```
letters = ["c","d","e","f","g","a","h","c","fis","cis","dis"]
```

I have a really long word list with one word per list and want to use

```
with open(...) as f:
for line in f:
    if
```

to check if each word is part of that "language" and then save it to another file.

my problem is how to alter

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.compile('^[abilrstu]+$')
>>> m.match('australia') is not None
True
>>> m.match('dummy') is not None
False
>>> m.match('australian') is not None
False
```

so it also matches with "fis","cis" and so on.

e.g. "fish" is a match but "ifsh" is not a match.

Comment: Check is this you wanna do `(^|\b)([cdefgahc]fis|cis|dis)+(\b|$)` https://regex101.com/r/RzYRIs/1/

Comment: im guessing that `"h"` needs to be a `"b"`

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Not necessarily: the German system (which is obviously the one in use here), calls H what in English-speaking countries is called B, and uses B for what in English-speaking countries is called B-flat.

Comment: ooh, i did not know that, thanks @BoarGules

Comment: @BoarGules is correct, German notation system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `^(fis|cis|dis|[abcfhg])+$` will do the job.

Some deconstruction of what's going on here:

- `|` workds like OR conjunction
- `[...]` denotes "any symbol from what's inside the brackets"
- `^` and `$` stand for beginning and end of line, respectively
- `+` stands for "1 or more time"
- `( ... )` stands for grouping, needed to apply `+`/`*`/`{}` modifiers. Without grouping such modifiers applies to closest left expression

Alltogether this "reads" as "whole string is one or more repetition of fis/cis/dis or one of abcfhg"

Comment: You probably want + rather than *

Comment: Well, I think that empty string may be considered as line made of any characters ;) But in real case with matching against corpus this shouldn't make any difference

Comment: worked for me with a + at the end. please do elaborate the code a bit as @DebanjanB pointed out. you are welcome to use my code that I put in the question

Answer (score 3):

This function works, it doesn't use any external libraries:

```
def func(word, letters):
    for l in sorted(letters, key=lambda x: x.length, reverse=True):
        word = word.replace(l, "")
    return not s
```

it works because `if s==""`, then it has been decomposed into your letters.

---

#### Update:

*It seems that my explanation wasn't clear. `WORD.replace(LETTER, "")` will replace the note/LETTER in WORD by nothing, **here is an example :***

```
func("banana", {'na'})
```

it will replace every `'na'` in `"banana"` by nothing (`''`)

the result after this is `"ba"`, which is not a note

`not ""` means `True` and `not "ba"` is false, this is syntactic sugar.

***here is another example :***

```
func("banana", {'na', 'chicken', 'b', 'ba'})
```

it will replace every `'chicken'` in `"banana"` by nothing (`''`)

the result after this is `"banana"`

it will replace every `'ba'` in `"banana"` by nothing (`''`)

the result after this is `"nana"`

it will replace every `'na'` in `"nana"` by nothing (`''`)

the result after this is `""`

it will replace every `'b'` in `""` by nothing (`''`)

the result after this is `""`

`not ""` is `True` ==> HURRAY IT IS A MELODY !

**note:** The reason for the `sorted` by length is because otherwise, the second example would not have worked. The result after deleting "b" would be "a", which can't be decomposed in notes.

Comment: I dont quite understand, can you please elaborate how this code works?

Comment: even though stackoverflow doesn't want me to use the comments for this: thank you for taking the time to explain how it works and providing a non regex solution. I accepted the other one because I asked in the question how to alter the regex, so your answer strictly an answer to my question. still upvote because it is an interesting alternative.

Comment: And I thank you for asking when you didn't understand, the objective of SO is to provide answers and to learn. I am glad I accomplished those objectives.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the number of letters of all units (names of musical notes), which are in the word, and compare this number to the length of the word.

```
from collections import Counter

units = {"c","d","e","f","g","a","h", "fis","cis","dis"}

def func(word, units=units):
    letters_count = Counter()
    for unit in units:
        num_of_units = word.count(unit)
        letters_count[unit] += num_of_units * len(unit) 
        if len(unit) == 1:
            continue
        # if the unit consists of more than 1 letter (e.g. dis)
        # check if these letters are in one letter units
        # if yes, substruct the number of repeating letters
        for letter in unit:
            if letter in units:
                letters_count[letter] -= num_of_units
    return len(word) == sum(letters_count.values())

print(func('disc'))
print(func('disco'))    
# True
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with tkinter window opening to choose file:

```
import re
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

m = re.compile('^(fis|ges|gis|as|ais|cis|des|es|dis|[abcfhg])+$')
matches = list()
filename = fd.askopenfilename()


with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if m.match(str(line).lower()) is not None:
            matches.append(line[:-1])


print(matches)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54390824/2) to the question [find all words in a certain alphabet with multi character letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54390824/find-all-words-in-a-certain-alphabet-with-multi-character-letters) by the OP [Nivatius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3503111/nivatius) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>